# How to convert path param to class in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jpa-2.0

Suppose code is like,

```
@Path("/app/{resource}")    //Suppose resource comes as Apple or Mango.
@Produces(value=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
public class AppResource { 

    @GET
    public Response getResource(@PathParam("resource") String resource) {
    // Here want to convert resource to Apple or Mango class so that I can create a List<Apple> or List<Mango>.
    }
}
```

Basically I want a generic List as List<Apple> or List<Mango> depending on the uri, whatever comes in {resource}.

Comment: Since response will be `JSON`, and there are no types there, a `List<Object>` is perfectly fine. It's up to you to only put `Apple` or `Mango` objects into the list, if that's what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to have explicit `List<Apple>` and `List<Mango>` lists, then you need to write the code something like this:

```
@GET
public Response getResource(@PathParam("resource") String resource) {
    List<?> list;
    switch (resource) {
        case "apples":
            list = getApples();
            break;
        case "mangos":
            list = getMangos();
            break;
        default:
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
    return Response.ok(list);
}

private List<Apple> getApples() {
    List<Apple> appleList = new ArrayList<>();
    // add apples
    return appleList;
}

private List<Mango> getMangos() {
    List<Mango> mangoList = new ArrayList<>();
    // add mangos
    return mangoList;
}
```

The `default` clause in the `switch` statement ensures that a request for something like `/app/sailboats` will fail with a normal `404` "Page Not Found" error.